# I am not able to use image from internet

Tags: android, web-services, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am calling a image from url for my image view, but it does not appear.
my emulator browser run perfectly but any app that use internet does not run,
i have given user permission in manifest file.
anyone please help.

this is my code

```
    package com.example.simpleimage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Simpleimage extends Activity {


    private String Url;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Url = "http://developer.android.com/images/dialog_progress_bar.png";

        ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv);
                  Drawable drawable = LoadImageFromWebOperations(Url);
                  iv.setImageDrawable(drawable);



    }

    private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
         try {
                InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
                Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
                return d;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exc=" + e);
                return null;
            }
    }

}
```

Comment: post the code snippet that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that you are not on proxy network,if you are then set the proxy in emulator,or use the mobile to test your app.

The simplest and the best way is to do the following: This has been done for Android Emulator 2.2

Click on Menu

Click on Settings

Click on Wireless & Networks

Go to Mobile Networks

Go to Access Point Names

Here you will Telkila Internet, click on it.

In the Edit access point section, input the "proxy" and "port"
Also provide the Username and Password,

rest of the fields leave them blank.

Answer (score 0):

First Set in Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

After pass your url link in below method that will return bitmap
like this

```
imgView.setImageBitmap(getImage("Your url")) ;
public static Bitmap getImage(String url){
        Bitmap img = null ;
        try {
            URL feedImage = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)feedImage.openConnection();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img ;    
    }
```

Comment: i have tried it but it still does not return,i think some problem with proxy

Comment: some time large images not load with url,try with small image..i thing it posiible